# Replace items in sublists without flattening

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the folowing list:

```
tab1 = [['D001', None, None, None, 'Donald Duck', 'Organise a meeting with Scrooge McDuck', 'todo',  None],
 ['D002', None, None, None, 'Mickey Mouse','Organise a meeting with Minerva Mouse', 'done',  None],
 ['D003', None, None, None, 'Mickey Mouse', 'Organise a meeting with Daisy Duck', 'todo',  None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
```

I would like to replace the None value by "..." for each sublist that is not empty

I tried:

```
foo =[]
for row in tab1:
    if row[0] is not None:
        for cell in row:
            if cell is None:
                cell = "..."
            foo.append(cell)
```

But foo gives me:

```
['D001',
 '...',
 '...',
 '...',
 'Donald Duck',
 'Organise a meeting with Scrooge McDuck',
 'todo',
 '...',
 'D002',
...
```

Instead of:

```
[['D001',
 '...',
 '...',
 '...',
 'Donald Duck',
 'Organise a meeting with Scrooge McDuck',
 'todo',
 '...',]
 ['D002',
...
```

Comment: You have to add list in the list. But now you have just `foo` list and you keep adding to it.

Comment: @Rakesh thx, your solution changes all the None values for the last sublist, which is something I try to avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a nested list comprehension and only replacing values if there are non-None values in the list:

output = [[y if y else '...' for y in x] if any(x) else [y for y in x] for x in tab1]

Splitting this down to make it easier to parse:

First, change `None` values in a list:

```
a = ['A','B',None,'C','D',None]
# if we have a value in y leave it alone, otherwise change it to '...'
a = [y if y else '...' for y in a]
# a is now ['A','B','...','C','D','...']
```

Now only change `None` values if there are non-None values in the list. `any(a_list)` will return true if any of the values in `a_list` are not None.

```
a = ['A','B',None,'C','D',None]
b = [None,None,None,None,None,None]
a = [y if y else '...' for y in a] if any(a) else [y for y in a]
b = [y if y else '...' for y in b] if any(b) else [y for y in b]
# a changed as above, b unchanged
```

And finally wrap it up so it works on each list in a list of lists:

```
output = [[y if y else '...' for y in x] if any(x) else [y for y in x] for x in tab1]
```

Answer (score 2):

You were creating just one list, instead of a list of lists:

```
bar = []
for row in tab1:
    foo = []
    if row[0] is not None:
        for cell in row:
            if cell is None:
                cell = "..."
            foo.append(cell)
        bar.append(foo)

print(bar)
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to have temporary variable:

```
foo = []
for row in tab1:
    temp_list = []
    if row[0] is not None:
        for cell in row:
            if cell is None:
                cell = "..."
            temp_list.append(cell)
    foo.append(temp_list)
```

Answer (score 2):

well ,you could use `pandas` for this . To install pandas use `pip install pandas` or install anaconda

Convert the list of list to a pandas dataframe fill all the missing values with `...` and the convert it back to a list of list

```
import pandas as pd
tab1 = [['D001', None, None, None, 'Donald Duck', 'Organise a meeting with Scrooge McDuck', 'todo',  None],
 ['D002', None, None, None, 'Mickey Mouse','Organise a meeting with Minerva Mouse', 'done',  None],
 ['D003', None, None, None, 'Mickey Mouse', 'Organise a meeting with Daisy Duck', 'todo',  None],
 [None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None]]
df=pd.DataFrame(tab1)
df.fillna(value="...", inplace=True)
listoflist=df.values.tolist()
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[['D001', '...', '...', '...', 'Donald Duck', 'Organise a meeting with Scrooge McDuck', 'todo', '...'], ['D002', '...', '...', '...', 'Mickey Mouse', 'Organise a meeting with Minerva Mouse', 'done', '...'], ['D003', '...', '...', '...', 'Mickey Mouse', 'Organise a meeting with Daisy Duck', 'todo', '...'], ['...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...', '...']]
```

Comment: It's just basic Python operation. To use Pandas here is not necessary because no big data is here. Less dependencies, less problems.

Comment: The problem with your solution is that it changes the None values of the last sublist.

Answer (score 0):

Using comprehensions:

```
[['...' if y is None else y for y in x] for x in tab1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the list based on index values.

```
foo = tab1[:]
for row in range(0,len(tab1)):
    if tab1[row][0] is not None:
        for cell in range(0,len(tab1[row])):
            if tab1[row][cell] is None:
                foo[row][cell] = "..."
```

Comment: It seems very complicated, or even overengineering.

Comment: Ha. It is like traversing in a 2D list.